# Excel PowerPivot Count new and distinct items in a period not counted before

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

Assuming I have the following data table:

```
Period | ID
-----------
P1     | 1
P2     | 1
P1     | 2
P2     | 3
P1     | 2
```

I am intersted in the number of unique IDs / Period only if the ID has not been counted already in a pervious period, ordered alphabatically. IDs per period in the source themselves can already occure multiple times and shall count as 1 / peroid (distinct count).

Also the data source is not pre-ordered by period and I have no influence on the sort order.

So the result I would like to get in a Pivot is like:

```
Period | Number of Unique IDs not already counted
-------------------------------------------------
P1     | 2 # Because the are uniquelly ID 1 and 2 in the period
P2     | 1 # Only counting ID 3, because ID 1 has already been counted in period 1
```

Please help me with the DAX measure I can use in the Pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a measure written in DAX. It should work in a pivot table with the Period selected on the rows

```
DistinctID =
VAR PeriodsPerId =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        ALL ( T[ID] ),
        "ID", T[ID],
        "Period", CALCULATE ( MIN ( T[Period] ), ALLEXCEPT ( T, T[ID] ) )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( PeriodsPerId, [Period] IN VALUES ( T[Period] ) ) )
```

It works first by preparing a table variable containing the minimum period per ID and then filtering this table for the Periods in the current selection.
Of course, if the Period is selected through a dimension, substitute the dimension in the last VALUES

Comment: That mostly works! My input data is comming from different sources and I guess that setting a sort order in the data model is not respected by the DAX measure? At least the results seem to indicate that. Also I forgot to mention that IDs must be unique / period which I easily achieved by adding =VAR PeriodsPerId =
    *DISTINCT*(SELECTCOLUMNS (  .However I fail to use DAX ORDER BY on the source table.

Comment: There is no sorting concept in DAX measure. ORDER BY can be used in DAX Queries.
I don't understand the need to add DISTINCT, since the SELECTCOLUMNS that I wrote returns only one row per ID. I suspect that the sample table doesn't match your real model :) Anyway, I hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, which would require to reposition your columns as well as add a new column. This assumes you don't have duplicates in ID/Period combos. You didn't list any duplicates in your sample, so I'm making this assumption.

In my data, I have ID as column A and Period as column B.

Order your data by Period, ascending. Then in column C, you can use this formula to determine if that ID has been used before.

```
Cell C2 formula: =IF(VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,FALSE) = B2,1,0)
```

Copy it down and then create your pivot table, summing column C.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately I have > 1 Million columns and therefore I have to use PowerQuery & PowerPivot.